Pass output of command line to awk variable
I am trying to normalise a data file using the number of lines in a previous version of the data file. After reading these questions, I thought this could work:
awk -v num=$(wc -l my_first_file.bed) '{print $1, $2, $3, $4/num}' my_other_file.bed

but it throws this error:
awk: cmd. line:1: my_first_file.bed
awk: cmd. line:1:              ^ syntax error

Protecting the . with a backslash doesn't change anything, nor does using backticks instead of $().
How can I use the output of wc -l as an awk variable? This will all be happening inside a snakemake pipeline, so I am somewhat limited in terms of flexibility.
Contents of my_other_file.bed:
chrUn_KI270548v1    0   50  0.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    50  192 1.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    192 497 0.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    497 639 1.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    639 723 0.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    723 860 1.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    860 865 2.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    865 879 1.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    879 991 2.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    991 1002    3.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    1002    1021    2.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    1021    1093    1.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    1093    1133    2.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    1133    1222    1.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    1222    1235    2.00000
chrUn_KI270548v1    1235    1364    1.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    0   16  4.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    16  46  5.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    46  48  6.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    48  95  7.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    95  117 8.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    117 130 9.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    130 136 8.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    136 138 7.00000
chrUn_KI270590v1    138 139 6.00000


wc -l filename will output a line containing two columns; the number of lines and the filename:
$ wc -l .profile
27 .profile

Your awk code gets confused when you are trying to divide using this string.
If you redirect the contents of the file into wc -l, then the wc utility will not be able to output the file's name and will only output the number of newlines in the file:
$ wc -l <.profile
27

So, change your code to this:
awk -v num=$(wc -l <my_first_file.bed) '{print $1, $2, $3, $4/num}' my_other_file.bed

Alternatively, let awk do the counting:
awk 'FNR == NR { lines++; next } { print $1, $2, $3, $4/lines }' my_first_file.bed my_other_file.bed

or,
awk 'FNR == NR { lines++; next } { $4 /= lines; print }' my_first_file.bed my_other_file.bed

Here, we give awk both files to work with, but while reading the first file, all we do is increment the lines variable. When starting to read the second file, the FNR == NR condition is no longer true (the number of records read from the current file is no longer the same as the number of records read overall), and we start executing the second block instead.
This assumes that the first file is never empty.
If you want the output to be tab-delimited, then don't forget to set OFS="\t" for awk.

Or awk 'lines=(NR-FNR){$4 /= lines} 1' my_first_file.bed my_other_file.bed.

Or even shorter: awk 'NR>FNR{$4/=(NR-FNR)} 1' ...

Just realised that I probably do want to use the num=$(wc -l <my_first_file.bed) because I'm getting the other data from a pipe... any way to use the FNR trick with piped data? How do I tell awk which data to read first?

@Whitehot If you want to pipe the data to the awk command then just replace the name of the file whose data you're piping with /dev/stdin on awk's command line.

Try running just wc -l my_first_file.bed:
$ wc -l my_first_file.bed
24 my_first_file.bed

So, your command gets expanded by the shell to
awk -v num=24 my_first_file.bed '{print $1, $2, $3, $4/num}' my_other_file.bed`

which makes my_first_file.bed your Awk command, which of course is not valid Awk syntax.
One way you could solve this would be to change your wc -l my_first_file.bed command to only output the first column. For example, something like this:
awk -v num=$(wc -l my_first_file.bed | cut -d' ' -f1) '{print $1, $2, $3, $4/num}' my_other_file.bed

This uses space as the delimiter for the output of cut to just pass the number of lines to your variable.

You can do this completely within awk by passing two files as operands:
awk 'NR==FNR{lines++;next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4/lines}' my_first_file.bed my_other_file.bed

This will do the following:

While processing the first file (indicated by NR, the global line-counter, being equal to FNR, the per-file line-counter), we simply increase the line count but skip execution to the next line afterwards.
While processing the next file, we print all columns, but divide the 4th one by the value lines, which is no longer incremented because NR is now larger then FNR

Note that this will not work if my_first_file.bed is empty.
